# Best way to read integers from a text file into an array

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

Assume i have a text file like this.

```
1 4 6
2 3    
5 8 9 4
2 1
1
```

What i want to do is to store them into a 2d array exactly how they are represented. After some googling and reading i came up with the following code.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myData.txt")));     

while (s.hasNextLine())
{
    String myStr = s.nextLine();
    x = 0;
    for ( int y = 0; y <= myStr.length(); y+=2)
    {
        myStr = myStr.trim();
        tempStr = myStr.substring(y, y+1)
        num[row][coln] = Integer.parseInt(tempStr);
        coln++
    }
    row++;
}
```

It works okay, but for integers that have only 1 digit. But what if i have integers of different length. How can i do it to dynamically check length of integers?

For example, i want to store this text file in an 2d array

```
13 4 652
2 343    
5 86 9 41
2 18
19
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be very much helpful. Thanks

Comment: Since you have a ragged array anyway, is there a reason not to use a `List`?

Comment: Oh since i was merely testing the program out to get the required functionality i needed, i used what i was most comfortable with. Ur point is taken anyway, will use a List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split()` for Strings.  If you use white-space as a delimiter, it will return an array of Strings, where each number in the line will map to one slot in the array.  Then, loop through the array and use `Integer.parseInt()`.

Another way to do it would be to feed the output from `nextLine()` into another `Scanner` and use `nextInt()` to retrieve the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nextInt method of scanner class it will give you integer value one by one.

Firslty you schould use hasnextXXX method to check that is there any integer value in your file like

```
scanner.hasNextInt()
```

Than you can write a program like

```
import java.util.*;

public class ScannerDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myData.txt")));     


      while (scanner.hasNext()) {
         if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("integer present" + scanner.nextInt());
         }
         System.out.println("no integer" + scanner.next());
      }
      scanner.close();
   }
```

}

From the JavaDocs, the nextInt() method will throw these exceptions under these conditions:

```
InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range
NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted
IllegalStateException - if this scanner is closed
```

Comment: Im sorry to ask. But why is the scanner cascaded unnecessarily?
    scanner = s = new Scanner ( new buffered...); //literally this is what happens right?

Comment: firstly i was thinking to convert string to scanner than i took inpt like you and forget to edit next line

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
scan.useDelimiter("\\Z");
String content = scan.next();
ArrayList output=new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Inteher> inner=new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] a1=content.split("\n");
for(String a:a1){
String a2=a1.plit(" ");
for(String b:a2){
inner=new ArrayList<Integer>();
inner.add(Integer.parseInt(b));
}
output.add(inner);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
    String[] a = mystr.split(" +");
    num[i] = new int[a.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        num[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(a[j]);
    }
```

I would also change the first part as follows

```
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myData.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int[][] num = new int[lines.size()][];
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
try {

        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(s);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        int[][] values = new int[numRows][numCols];

        int numRows = br.readLine();
        int numCols = br.readLine();

        String delims = "\\s+";
        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
            for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                values[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For the text file, set it out like this:

```
10 // amount of numbers across
7 // amount of numbers down
6 6 6 6 6 65 6 6 6 6
6 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
6 6 6 6 6 6 72 6 6 6
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
6 6 89 6 6 6 6 345 6 6
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

You put the across and down numbers in so when it reads the integers into the 2D array, it knows the width and height.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It's significantly faster to use a `MappedByteBuffer` and read this in as binary, and process the numbers that way. In my experiments in [this similar context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606833/fastest-way-to-sum-integers-in-text-file), it was three times as fast. There is a huge overhead to reading line by line, in two respects:

1. The garbage collector goes crazy because you're creating and discarding so many `String` objects.
2. You process every character twice: once when constructing the `String`, and then once more when turning it into numbers. If you split the `String` and then convert each one, you process each character three times.

It depends rather on whether you want speed or concise and simple code. There's no doubt that the `String` approach is easier to understand, so it's better if you know your file will always be small; but if it might get huge, you really should look at a binary approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but why don't you just read it in like this?

```
list1 = [map(int,x.strip().split()) for x in open("/ragged.txt")]

for z in list1:
    for y in z:
        print y,
    print
```

It prints the following integers (same as file contents):

```
1 4 6
2 3
5 8 9 4
2 1
1
```

It works for longer integers too.